# After Mavericks 10.9.2 Update, problems running Keepass/Mono

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz, sound-volume

I have a rMBP 13" late 2013 model and just updated Mavericks today to 10.9.2 (Software  OS X 10.9.2 (13C64))

I have been using the OSX package of keepass from [here (Openix)](http://keepass2.openix.be/) without any issues before updating.

After updating, if I try to open keepass, the laptop hangs (i get the beachball of doom) and the mono process uses upwards of 98% of the cpu untill I kill it.

I have the mono runtime (version 3.2.7) and XQuartz 2.7.5 (xorg-server 1.14.4), installed. I am not very knowledgable as to how to troubleshoot to see if there is mono or x11 issue, I just installed them to be able to use keepass on my macbook.

IS there anyone else experiencing this same issue?

What steps could I take to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: I am still unabel to get this to work again! FOr the time being I have switched to using the keepasx2 Alpha release found here: https://www.keepassx.org/news/2013/12/420 and I suggest any other keepass & OSX users do the same! The only missing tool now is the ability to work with the keepasshttp plugin, hopefully future development can resolve this.

Comment: Hi Shane, I've had a very similar experience on a fresh Mavericks install.  In my case KeePass is extremely slow to open and then completely unresponsive to input until it eventually crashes.

Comment: I will try this aagain this upcoming weekend - I want to try it with the newer version of mono and keepass. For now I have been using [KeepassX2.0](http://www.keepassx.org/) and although I really miss autotype, this thing runs circles around Keepass on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

A useful troubleshooting tool for any OS X application is `opensnoop` which lets you see file activity on your system. If you run `sudo opensnoop -v | grep mono-sgen` before launching KeePass you'll be able to watch which files it is opening as it launches.

I ran this to troubleshoot another question about KeePass problems and on my system the first launch of KeePass generates a lot of activity where Mono is opening and caching the fonts on the system in `~/.cache/fontconfig`. While it is doing this the application appears to be doing nothing, as the UI doesn't appear until this task is complete which takes minutes on my system. Luckily it only seems to want to do this once, as subsequent starts are about what I'd expect.

And this is only guesswork but upgrading Mono, XQuartz or KeePass or installing other fonts might prompt Mono to regenerate this cache, resulting in another one off slow application launch. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen in a new user account? If it does, that issue is system wide and you may need to remove the app and wait for a compatible version. If not, it means there may be a preference file interfering with normal use. That's a good place to start. Test user accounts are magical :3

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior is identical when trying to open using a new user account :( For the time being I guess I could just running a VM 24x7 just to have access to keepass but it certainly is not ideal.